# Meteor error message: "Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting."

Tags: meteor

I am just starting to build a new Meteor app. The only thing I have done so far is add one Collection. It will start, run fine for about 5 minutes, and then give me the error message  "Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting."

What is failing to receive keepalive from what? I assume this has something to do with Mongo since that is the only thing I have added. Googling the error message turns up nothing except Meteor sites that are just showing this error message instead of the their app.

My MongoDB collection already had data in it that was not created by Meteor and it is over 4GB if that makes any difference.

This is the complete app.

```
pitches_sum = new Meteor.Collection( 'pitches_sum' );

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
  return "Welcome to my site.";
  };

  Template.hello.events = {
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  };
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
  console.log( '**asdf**' );        
  });
}
```

If I comment out the `pitches_sum = new Meteor.Collection( 'pitches_sum' );` line, then I don't think I will get the error message any more.

Comment: Try specifying collection in server only, right now it is be loaded for client too. If still gives same error meaning issue is with server to mongo connection.

Comment: I bumped into this same problem w/o a large data set, but with something like 16 connected peers all trying to read the same ~100 records or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was being caused by my large data set and autopublish. Since autopublish was on, Meteor was trying to send the whole 4GB collection down to the client. Trying to process all the data prevented the client from responding to the server's keep alive pings. Or something to that effect.

Removing autopublish with `meteor remove autopublish` and then writing my own publish and subscribe functions fixed the problem.