# Can't rerun meteor leaderboard on AWS EC2 micro T1 instance after failing keepalive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, meteor, vnc

I'm unable to run a Meteor leaderboard demo after a failed keepalive error on an AWS EC2 micro.T1 instance.  If I start from a freshly booted Amazon Machine Instance (AMI) I'm able to run the leaderboard demo at localhost:3000 from Firefox when I'm connected with a VNC client (TightNVC Viewer).  It runs very, very slowly, but it runs.

If I fail to interact with it soon enough however I get these messages

I2051-00:03:03.173(0)?Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code:1
=> Meteor server restarted

From that point forward everything on that instance runs at a glacial pace.  Switching back to the Firefox window takes 3 minutes.  when I try to connect to //localhost:3000 Firefox I usually get a message about a script no longer running and eventually the terminal window adds this to what I wrote above:

I2051-00:06:02.443(0)?Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code:1
=> Meteor server restarted
I2051-00:08:17.227(0)?Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code:1
=> Your application is crashing.  Waiting for file change.

Can anyone translate for me what is happening?

I'm wondering whether the t1.micro instance I'm running is just too under-powered or because it's not shutting down meteor properly thereby leaving an instance of MongoDB running and trying to launch another.

I'm using Amazon Machine Image ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20130411.1 (ami-70f96e40)  which says this about it's configuration:

Size:   t1.micro
ECUs:   up to 2
vCPUs:  1 
Memory (GiB):   0.613 
Instance Storage (GiB): EBS only 
EBS-Optimized Available:    - 
Netw. Performance:  -Very Low

Micro instances
Micro instances are a low-cost instance option, providing a small amount of CPU resources. They are suited for lower throughput applications, and websites that require additional compute cycles periodically, but are not appropriate for applications that require sustained CPU performance. Popular uses for micro instances include low traffic websites or blogs, small administrative applications, bastion hosts, and free trials to explore EC2 functionality.

If my guess is right, can anyone suggest an AMI suitable for Meteor development?

Thanks

Comment: and does anyone know how to restart Meteor cleanly so that I don't have to reboot the instance?

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173000/meteor-error-message-failed-to-receive-keepalive-exiting)

Try to remove `meteor remove autopublish`

Comment: Can you clue me in as to what you're thinking here?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the app on ec2? I have been able to run apps on a micro instance so I don't see why this should be an issue.

If you are running it by using 'meteor' as you would locally that's probably the issue. You get way better performance when running it as a node app, this typically isn't an issue when developing locally but may be too much for a ec2 micro.

What you want to do is 'meteor bundle example.tgz', upload that to the server and run it as a node app.

Here is a guide that I remember using a while ago to get it done on ec2:
http://julien-c.fr/2012/10/meteor-amazon-ec2/

You shouldn't need to use VNC either, you can access it from your own computer in a browser using the public address your instance gets assigned.

If you get a node fibers error message which is pretty common then cd into bundle/program/server do 'npm uninstall fibers' and then 'npm install fibers'

Comment: Awesome!  I'll check it out.  Any idea why it's so much slower running from the 'meteor' command line (that's, indeed, how I was running it)?  I've never been successful running the app from my public url when deploying it the way I've been doing but maybe after bundling it will work.  Looks like a great link too.