# Meteor: “Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.”

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm working on a project which uses Npm request package for making request to an API server. On getting response, the callback processes the returned response. During this response processing I get the error: Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting. The following code will help you understand.

```
 request({url: 'http://api-link-from-where-data-is-to-be-fetched'
 },

 function (err,res,body) {

        //The code for processing response  

 }
```

Anybody can help me please who knows how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This might help answer this for you:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1302

The last post on that page says:

Note that this is just a behavior of the develop-mode meteor run (and any hosting environment that chooses to turn on the keepalive option, which probably isn't most of them), not a production issue. And in any case, if your Node process is churning CPU for seconds, it's not going to be able to respond to any network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

this post might help you : [Meteor error message: "Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173000/meteor-error-message-failed-to-receive-keepalive-exiting)

Removing autopublish with  meteor remove autopublish and then writing my own publish and subscribe functions fixed the problem.