# meteor restart shows error in terminal console "Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting"

Tags: meteor

Currently I am coding in Meteor 0.9.3, Ubuntu 14.04 and VMware 10

Every time I edit my code, meteorjs takes too much time for restart and ubuntu terminal console shows error. Sometimes it shows "unexpected error" in chrome also.

```
=> Meteor server restarted
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20140927-13:24:11.922(5.5)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20140927-13:25:27.484(5.5)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Client modified -- refreshing
=> Exited from signal: SIGUSR2
=> Meteor server restarted
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20140927-13:33:04.041(5.5)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20140927-13:37:47.871(5.5)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted
=> Client modified -- refreshing
I20140927-13:42:04.362(5.5)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Client modified -- refreshing
=> Meteor server restarted
```

[image: meteor package list that i used in my project]

[image: ubuntu terminal console]

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173000/meteor-error-message-failed-to-receive-keepalive-exiting

Comment: I have the same issue here on Mac OS, Meteor 0.9.2.2. I am pretty much sure it's not a problem with autopublish.

Comment: @apendua i removed autopublish but error still esisting

Comment: @Paul there is no collection in my app and no server-side, i just developing client side view in spreadjs

Comment: Well, I don't know.  I simply pass along the link as I find it quickly. Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling meteor?  Perhaps on a fresh vm?  [Nitrous.io](http://nitrous.io) is a good vm provider for this sort of testing.

Comment: Confirm that I see this issue quite often on Linux Mint, Meteor 0.9.3 and 0.9.2.2 as well. Not every reload but often ;/

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2536). The fix is currently on the development branch and I assume will be part of the next update after 0.9.3. As suggested by Nick Martin, you can add:

```js
process.argv = _.without(process.argv, '--keepalive');
Meteor.startup(function () { console.log("LISTENING"); });
```

Somewhere in your server code and that should provide a workable but hacky solution for now.

Comment: Doesn't work. The code somehow gets reverted back! Also, I tried updating .meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/webapp.js
inserting a return statement inside the initKeepalive function. Some meteor ghost too reverts the file back!!!